# JavaScript: Append object properties as child elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, createelement, object-properties

I have an array of object and I'm trying to create HTML elements for each object and for each object's property, but got stuck, when I try to loop through containerDiv and appending object's properties as children elements.

- I want to create a div for each object with the class name of
  containerDiv;
- I want to loop through containerDiv;
- I want to create an element for each object property and append them
  as children elements to containerDiv;

My code sample looks like this:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');

function createHTMLElements() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
        var containerDiv = document.createElement('div');
        containerDiv.className = 'container';
        parent.appendChild(containerDiv);

        // Loop through containerDiv and append object properties as child elements
    }
}

var arrayOfObjects = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        surname: 'Doe'
    },
    {
        name: 'David',
        surname: 'Mills'
    }
]
```

Comment: Hello, why you don't use JQuery?

Comment: I'm trying to switch to Vanilla JS. I want to understand it well. I know jQuery is a lot easier, but I prefer this way :)

Comment: jQuery has its own troubles. Better off sticking with Vanilla these days unless you're supporting really old browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a loop over the current object in the array.

```
for (var p in arrayOfObjects[i]) {
  containerDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("p"))
    .textContent = p + ": " + arrayOfObjects[i][p];
}
```

---

DEMO:

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');

var arrayOfObjects = [{
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Doe'
  },
  {
    name: 'David',
    surname: 'Mills'
  }
];

createHTMLElements();

function createHTMLElements() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
    var containerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    containerDiv.className = 'container';
    parent.appendChild(containerDiv);


    for (var p in arrayOfObjects[i]) {
      containerDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("p"))
        .textContent = p + ": " + arrayOfObjects[i][p];
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 2px dashed #333;
  margin: 4px;
}

.container>p {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div id=parent></div>
```

---

Here's a demo that doesn't use a loop but uses a helper function to make cleaner code.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');

var arrayOfObjects = [{
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Doe'
  },
  {
    name: 'David',
    surname: 'Mills'
  }
];

createHTMLElements();

function createHTMLElements() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
    var containerDiv = create('div', {className: "container"}, parent);
    
    var obj = arrayOfObjects[i];
    create("p", {textContent: "name: " + obj.name}, containerDiv);
    create("p", {textContent: "surname: " + obj.surname}, containerDiv);
  }
}

function create(type, props, parent) {
  var el = document.createElement(type);
  for (var p in props) {
    el[p] = props[p];
  }
  if (parent) {
    parent.appendChild(el);
  }
  return el;
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 2px dashed #333;
  margin: 4px;
}

.container>p {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div id=parent></div>
```

Comment: Your answer is also great. Can you please explain what's going on in second for loop?

  for (var p in arrayOfObjects[i])

Comment: @BekaSomkhishvili: That's just a loop over the current object in the array. It visits each property of the object one at a time, and assigns the current `key` the the variable `p`. So then we just create a new `<p>` element, add it to the `containerDiv`, and the `<p>` element's `.textContent` to the key `p`, as well as the value of `p` in the object `arrayOfObjects[i][p]`.

Comment: If you don't want a loop, then I'd suggest creating a helper function so you're not writing repetitive code.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I like the second approach a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the child element using same `document.cretateElement` . Also you need to call the function

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [{
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Doe'
  },
  {
    name: 'David',
    surname: 'Mills'
  }
]
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');

function createHTMLElements() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
    var containerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    containerDiv.className = 'container';
    var nameDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var surnameDiv = document.createElement('div');
    nameDiv .innerHTML = arrayOfObjects[i].name;
    surnameDiv .innerHTML = arrayOfObjects[i].surname;
    containerDiv.append(nameDiv );
    containerDiv.append(surnameDiv);
    parent.appendChild(containerDiv);

  }
}
createHTMLElements()
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed. The way I was trying to achieve the same result was way more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more generic and structured approach. Refactoring becomes more easy for it provides methods for each special "create and append" task. Making use of `reduce` as list iterator method comes with the advantage of staying more flexible with e.g. what kind of "container" to choose by providing kind of a configuration to each "container" creating process.

```js
var objectList = [{
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'Doe'
}, {
  name: 'David',
  surname: 'Mills'
}];

var elmContainer = document.createElement('li');
elmContainer.className = 'container';

function createAndAppendContainerChild(itemKey, itemValue, parentNode) {
  var elmChild = document.createElement('span');
  elmChild.className = itemKey;
  elmChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode(itemValue));
  parentNode.appendChild(elmChild);
}
function createAndAppendContainer(config, item) {
  var elmContainer = config.blueprintNode.cloneNode();
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function (key) {
    createAndAppendContainerChild(key, item[key], elmContainer);
  });
  config.parentNode.appendChild(elmContainer);
  return config;
}

objectList.reduce(createAndAppendContainer, {
  parentNode   : document.querySelector('#container-parent'),
  blueprintNode: elmContainer
});
```

```css
.surname:before {
  content: ' '
}
```

```html
<ul id="container-parent"></ul>
```